# C# GiantKillerRobotMiniGame

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have a robot class which has 2 proprieties:

1. `int RobotHealth;`
2. `public Intensity Intens;` which is an enum you can see below:

```
enum Intensity
{
    Low = 10,
    Medium = 20,
    High = 30,
    Kill = 40,
}
```

Here is the robot class and the method FireLaser which needs to calculate the difference between the Health of the target and the value of the Intesity which can be Low, Medium, High, Kill. So the problem is the method FireLaser which needs to calculate the difference batten the current target health and the intensity of the laser doesn't do it all and I can't understand why:

```
    internal class Robot
    {
        int HealthRobot;
        public Intensity Intens;
        public bool isActive()
        {

            if (HealthRobot > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public Robot  (int healthRobot , Intensity intensity)
        {
           HealthRobot = healthRobot;
           Intens = intensity;  
        } 


        public int FireLaser()
        {
            var Damage =  (int)Robot.Intens;
            var cth = this Target();
            int Health  = cth.Health - Damage;
            Health = cth.Health;
            return Health;
        }
    }
```

And I created a separated class for the target which verifies if the target is still alive

```
 public class Target
    {

        public int Health;
        int Damage;
        public bool CurrentTargetisAlive ()
        {

            if ( Health > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
public  class Planets
    {
       public Target[] Habitant;

        public Planets( Target[] habitant)
        {
            this.Habitant = habitant;
        }
    }
```

To rephrase my problem is that I want to do a mini game were a robot kills all planets habitants were Planets is an object defined by an array of targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to remake my little program so the first problem was at the the method which calculates FireLasesr because it generates a new target each time it fires
so I created a property in robot for Target for Current Target and an array of targets for all targets.

```
public Target CurrentTarget;
public Target[] Targets;
```

Here is the method wich calculates FireLaser properly and another one wich finds the next target.

```
   public void FireLaserAt(Target CurrentTarget)            
    {
       
       CurrentTarget.Health =  CurrentTarget.Health - (int)EyeLasserIntensity;
        Console.WriteLine($"Robot attacks {CurrentTarget} and deal {(int)EyeLasserIntensity} damage");
       Console.WriteLine($"So {CurrentTarget} remains with {CurrentTarget.Health}");
    }
  public void AcquireNextTarget()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{CurrentTarget} a murit");
        if ( i < Targets.Length - 1)
        CurrentTarget = Targets[++i];
        else
        {
            Active = false;
        }
```

Also I crated 3 more classes which inherith the class Target
(The only think I changed to all the others classes are the Health and the Name) and an example of such a class is

```
 internal class Humans:Target
{
   
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Human";
    }
    public Humans()
    {
       Health = 100;
    }
}
```

And the planet which has a earth class which inherits it and defines which types of targets populate the planet earth in this case

```
 public class Planets
{
    public Target[] Targets;
    public bool ContainsLife()
    {
        for ( int i = 0;  i < Targets.Length; i ++ )
        {
           
            if ( Targets[i].Alive() == true)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public Earth ( )
    {
        Targets = new Target[] { new Animals(), new SuperHeroes(), new Humans()  };
        
    }
```

And finally here is the main code who which kills all the alive targets in the planet

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.initialize();
        robot.EyeLasserIntensity = Intensity.Kill;
        robot.Targets = new Target[] { new SuperHeroes() , new Animals(), new SuperHeroes(), new Humans() };
        robot.CurrentTarget = robot.Targets[0];
        Planets earth = new Earth();
        Console.WriteLine($"Statut robot active: {robot.Active}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Statut pamanul contine viata: {earth.ContainsLife()}");
        while ( robot.Active && earth.ContainsLife())
        {
            if (robot.CurrentTarget.Alive())
            {
                robot.FireLaserAt(robot.CurrentTarget);
            }
            else
                robot.AcquireNextTarget();
        }
        robot.Active = false;
        Console.WriteLine($"Statut robot active: {robot.Active}");
        
    }
```

Comment: So the main code verifys if the robot is active and if the planets in this case earth contains life is true and fire laser at all targets

Comment: And don't forget about the classes which inherit the target class you can play with those as much as you like